# Ajax Data is not properly assigning to jQuery Input with the same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on Invoicing System in which **Rate(Amount)** value automatically changes on changing the Product(Item).

The issue I am facing is on Changing the first Product all rest of the Product Rate changes to Rate of the first Item.

Code to change the Rate on selecting Product. (jQuery)

```html
//Values and Inputs
$(document).on('change', '.Item', function() {
    var Item = $('.Item').closest('.Item').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'AjaxPrice.php',
        data: { Item: Item },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.Rate').val(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Code of Predefined Table

```html
<tbody class="TableBody">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 220px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control Item" name="Item" id="Item" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="QTV" min="1" name="QTV" id="QTV" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00" required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right Rate" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input step="any" id="Disc" name="Disc" type="number" min="0" name="" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="SubTotal" class="form-control text-right" id="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger DelRow">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Code to Add new Item

```html
$('#AddNewItem').click(function() { $('.TableBody').append(`
<tr>
  <td style="width: 220px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control Item" name="Item" id="Item" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required autocomplete="off">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="QTV" min="1" name="QTV" id="QTV" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00" required>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right Rate" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input step="any" id="Disc" name="Disc" type="number" min="0" name="" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="SubTotal" class="form-control text-right" id="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger DelRow">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
`); });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yea, so, there's no element with the className `Rate`. Maybe you meant to select by ID instead? Maybe the target element needs to be given said class?

Comment: Because you need to select the rate input in the row..... (and ids need to be unique)

Comment: @epascarello Yeah now i'm using unique Classes for each new Item(row)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your predefined table and the dynamic table-row are using the same classes and id's. 
So, if you call `$('.Rate').val(response);`, it will change all elements owning the class ".Rate".

One possible solution could be adding a increment number, like so:

```
$('#AddNewItem').click(function() {

var i = parseInt($('.TableBody').length)+1; 

$('.TableBody').append('
.
.
<td>
    <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right Rate_'+i+'" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
</td>
.
.
');
```

});

Of course you're free to use that on an other classname.

To grab that number to use it after your ajax-call is finisyou could add that number as data-attribute to the ".Item" element:

```
$('#AddNewItem').click(function() {

var i = parseInt($('.TableBody').length)+1; 

$('.TableBody').append('
.
.
<td>
    <input type="text" data-loop="'+i+'" class="form-control Item" name="Item" id="Item" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required autocomplete="off">
</td>
.
.
<td>
    <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right Rate_'+i+'" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
</td>
.
.
');
```

});

And your ajax function could be:

```
$(document).on('change', '.Item', function() {
var Item = $('.Item').closest('.Item').val();
var loop_id = $(this).data('loop');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AjaxPrice.php',
    data: { Item: Item },
    success: function(response) {
        $('.Rate_'+loop_id).val(response);
    }
});
```

});

-> Not sure if `loop_id` is available in success-scope, maybe you have to pass it with the ajax call and recieve it with `response`. By thisd way, i would recommend you to use JSON as dataType. Like so:

```
$(document).on('change', '.Item', function() {
var Item = $('.Item').closest('.Item').val();
var loop_id = $(this).data('loop');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AjaxPrice.php',
    dataType: 'JSON', 
    data: { Item: Item, loop_id:loop_id },
    success: function(response) {
        $('.Rate_'+response.loop_id).val(response.html);
    }
});
```

});

Hope it helps you a little out.

Comment: Not tested, by the way. If you find a typo, you may keep it :-)

Comment: Thank you, The concept was nearly same and that helped me. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: `var Item = $('.Item').closest('.Item').val();` is wrong.... not sure how it works unless there is only one Item

Answer (score 0):

Select the input that is in the row. You are selecting the first input

```
$(document).on('change', '.Item', function() {
    var item = this.value // get the item that was changed
    var row = $(this).closest("tr")  // get the table row the item is in
    var rate = row.find(".rate") // find the rate input in the row
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'AjaxPrice.php',
        data: { Item: Item },
        success: function(response) {
          rate.val(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @epascarello Your answer is correct but that's not what I was asking for. I just wanted to alter the Price of the specific row on Product change